# Problem with with DRCSim 2.2 tutorial

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey Guys,

I am new to Gazebo/ROS/DRC Simulator. I tried following  this tutorial:
[DRC Tutorial: Atlas Robot whole-body joint trajectory control](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.2/Atlas_control_over_ROS_topics_with_python)  to get me started. But I ran into this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "traj_yaml.py", line 79, in
>
> interpCommand = (1-ratio)*initialPosition + ratio *
> commandPosition ValueError: operands
> could not be broadcast together with
> shapes (0) (28)

Which after some debugging, I concluded that the function **jointStatesCallback** was not being called at all. After issuing the following command

**rosservice list**

I get a list that does not include **'/atlas/joint_states'**, which the program is trying to subscribe to.

I'll appreciate some insight as to what I am doing wrong here. The DRC Simulator works fine for other tutorials.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1733/problem-with-with-drcsim-2.2-tutorial/) by [danny.brown](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/255/danny.brown/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-03-11**:
`/atlas/joint_states` is actually a ros topic, so try `rostopic list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answer in comments.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0